# How to find the previous value different from another value in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I guess this task is easy, but I can't find out how to do it properly.

I have a dataframe which last column I have to use in order to select some rows. So I have the following df:

```
      packet_length  src_port  dst_port comm_type
1)    280             46306.0     443.0        10
2)    105             33105.0    9999.0        00
3)    105             33105.0    9999.0        00
4)    105             33105.0    9999.0        00
5)    127              9999.0   33105.0        00
6)    127              9999.0   33105.0        00
7)    127              9999.0   33105.0        00
8)    583             45914.0     443.0        01
9)    1066              443.0   46306.0        10
10)    73             46306.0     443.0        10
11)   278             46306.0     443.0        11
```

Then, I want to iterat over the last dataframe's columns thus when I found the value '00' get the previous **row** with comm_type value different from '00' or '11', and without considering the duplicates.

What I've tried so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('db.csv', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
df = df.head(n=10)


df_without_cons_dup = df.copy()

df_without_cons_dup = df_without_cons_dup.loc[df_without_cons_dup.comm_type.shift(-1) != df_without_cons_dup.comm_type]

df_without_cons_dup.reset_index(inplace=True)


df_00_01 = []
df_00_10 = []
df_11_01 = []
df_11_10 = []

tidx = 0
for indx, item in df_without_cons_dup.iterrows():
    if item.comm_type == '00':
        val = df_without_cons_dup.comm_type[indx-1]
        if val == '10':
            pkt_len = df_without_cons_dup.packet_length[indx-1]
            df_00_10.append(pkt_len)
        elif val == '01':
            pkt_len = df_without_cons_dup.packet_length[indx-1]
            df_00_01.append(pkt_len)
        else:
            continue
    elif item.comm_type == '11':
        val = df_without_cons_dup.comm_type[indx-1]
        if val == '10':
            pkt_len = df_without_cons_dup.packet_length[indx-1]
            df_11_10.append(pkt_len)
        elif val == '01':
            pkt_len = df_without_cons_dup.packet_length[indx-1]
            df_11_01.append(pkt_len)
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
```

But the problem I realized that deleting the dups is wrong because I'm maybe missing information. Also, despite of this code works, it doesn't take into account the fact that the previous element could be another '00' or '11'.

The empty lists should store the values i'm looking for, so for the dataframe a mentioned before, the expected output is:

```
df_00_01 = []
df_00_10 = [280]
df_11_01 = []
df_11_10 = [73]
```

I wish you could understand the question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your expected out put ?

Comment: What is the expected output and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
#first filter out duplicates of `00` and `11` values, keep first value only
df1 = df[~(df['comm_type'].ne(df['comm_type'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated() & \
     df['comm_type'].isin(['00','11']))]
print (df1)
     packet_length  src_port  dst_port comm_type
1)             280   46306.0     443.0        10
2)             105   33105.0    9999.0        00
8)             583   45914.0     443.0        01
9)            1066     443.0   46306.0        10
10)             73   46306.0     443.0        10
11)            278   46306.0     443.0        11

m1 = df1['comm_type'] == '00'
m2 = df1['comm_type'] == '11'
#get positions of values to numpy array and subtract 1 for previous value
#np.clip is for 0 instead -1 if first value is 00 or 11  
pos = df.columns.get_indexer(['packet_length','comm_type'])
a00 = df1.iloc[np.clip(np.where(m1)[0] - 1, 0, len(df)), pos]
a11 = df1.iloc[np.clip(np.where(m2)[0] - 1, 0, len(df)), pos]
print (a00)
    packet_length comm_type
1)            280        10

print (a11)
     packet_length comm_type
10)             73        10
```

---

```
df_00_01 = a00.loc[a00['comm_type'] == '01', 'packet_length'].tolist()
df_00_10 = a00.loc[a00['comm_type'] == '10', 'packet_length'].tolist()
df_11_01 = a11.loc[a11['comm_type'] == '01', 'packet_length'].tolist()
df_11_10 = a11.loc[a11['comm_type'] == '10', 'packet_length'].tolist()

print (df_00_01)
[]
print (df_00_10)
[280]
print (df_11_01)
[]
print (df_11_10)
[73]
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, but it doesn't work with my dataset. Just with that portion of it.

Comment: @sooaran - What is expected output from `df = pd.DataFrame({'packet_length':range(15), 'comm_type':['00','01','00','00','11','11','10','10','01','11','11','00','10','11','00']})` ? `df_00_01`, `df_00_10`, `df_11_01`, `df_11_10` ? Be free modify this sample Dataframe for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).